# Convert SELECT-ENDSELECT in for all entries with more table

Tags: sql, performance, select, extract, abap

I would like to convert this `SELECT-ENDSELECT` into `FOR ALL ENTRIES` to have better performance.

```
LOOP AT it_zgd_check_smc into wa_zgd_check_smc.

    SELECT *
      FROM ever
      INTO wa_ever
      WHERE anlage  EQ wa_euiinstln-anlage
      AND   einzdat <= wa_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio
      AND   auszdat >= wa_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio.
    ENDSELECT.

"---logic---"

ENDLOOP.
```

There are 2 tables : `EUIINSTLN` and `IT_ZGD_CHECK_SMC`. How can I do to convert it into `for all entries`?

Thank all.
regards.

Comment: The advice is to do everything at database level, the rule-of-thumb is to join the tables, `FOR ALL ENTRIES` is often not very fast and cannot be tuned by administrators to improve the performance. Can't you get rid of internal table `IT_ZGD_CHECK_SMC` and read directly from its source?

Comment: if you cannot do it on DB lever like Sandra said, make a [range](https://www.samplecodeabap.com/sap-range-table-example-abap/) from one of the tables (the smallest) and put the second in FAE using WHERE condition by that range

Comment: Does `it_zgd_check_smc` also come from a database table? If so, then it might be possible and even more efficient to query both tables with one SELECT by using a JOIN. If you would like us to show you how, please add the SELECT for the first table to your question.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the `SELECT - ENDSELECT` you can simply use `INTO TABLE` and loop over it afterwards. This is usually faster and you can do it (almost) every time.

```
    data: lt_ever like table of wa_ever.
    LOOP AT it_zgd_check_smc into wa_zgd_check_smc.
      SELECT *
        FROM ever
        INTO TABLE lt_ever
        WHERE anlage  EQ wa_euiinstln-anlage
        AND   einzdat <= wa_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio
        AND   auszdat >= wa_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio.
     LOOP AT lt_ever INTO wa_ever.
       "Put here what was in the SELECT - ENDSELECT previously.
     ENDLOOP.
   ENDLOOP.
```

Then you could use `FOR ALL ENTRIES` to get rid of one of the outer loops. If you use this, you can simply replace the workarea with the table. But you should make sure, that the table you're using is not empty. Otherwise the WHERE statement will act like an empty range (in other words, it will be ignored), so it gives you all entries from the database. So it would give you something like this:

```
    data: lt_ever like table of wa_ever.
    
    IF it_zgd_check_smc_st IS NOT INITIAL.
      SELECT *
        FROM ever
        INTO TABLE lt_ever
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_zgd_check_smc_st
        WHERE anlage  EQ wa_euiinstln-anlage
        AND   einzdat <= it_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio
        AND   auszdat >= it_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio.
     loop at lt_ever into wa_ever.
       "Put here what was in the SELECT - ENDSELECT previously.
     endloop.
   ENDIF.
```

You can't use a second table with for all entries, but you could build a range for the ***ANLAGE - field***. Just make sure you don't use an emtpy range again.

```
DATA: lt_ever LIKE TABLE OF wa_ever.
DATA: lr_anlage TYPE RANGE OF anlage.
DATA: lrs_anlage LIKE LINE OF lr_anlage.

lrs_anlage-sign = 'I'.
lrs_anlage-option = 'EQ'.
LOOP AT euiinstln INTO wa_euiinstln.
  lrs_anlage-low = wa_euiinstln-anlage.
  APPEND lrs_anlage TO lr_anlage.
ENDLOOP.


IF it_zgd_check_smc_st IS NOT INITIAL AND
   lr_anlage IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT *
    FROM ever
    INTO TABLE lt_ever
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_zgd_check_smc_st
    WHERE anlage  IN lr_anlage
    AND   einzdat <= it_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio
    AND   auszdat >= it_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio.
  LOOP AT lt_ever INTO wa_ever.
    "Put here what was in the SELECT - ENDSELECT previously.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
```

I don't know what the code is supposed to do, so I don't know how much of this is actually usefull for you. Not builing the range and looping over the ***euiinstln - table*** should be just as fast, since the ***EVER - Database*** should have an Index on the ***anlage - field*** anyways.

Comment: What if the table has millions of entries? Selecting into an internal table is definitely not a good idea then.

Comment: If the table has millions of entries you'll have severe runtime issues with a select endselect. Unless it overflows your memory of the internal table (in this case it realistically shouldn't), you're better of with selecting into a table.

Comment: yes,I would like to do all the extractions out of the loop-edloop  first, and then read the tables with the read table. But my problem is how can i do .

Comment: @herrberthaltsmaul no you won’t because select - endselect is nothing more than opening a cursor over a database set. Selecting everything into an internal table is insanity and normally a sing of poor programming skills.

Comment: @Jagger please properly inform yourself about how "select-endselect" and "select into table" works before you jugde someones programming skills on it. Here is a very good explanation why select-endselects are in fact slower:
[link](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/09/21/selectinto-table-faster-than-selectendselect-the-real-reason/)
I honestly didn't know the reason why before, but everyone who has used ABAP on a daily basis for a couple of years knows this from experience.