# Reading efficiently internal table by date fields with <= and >=

Tags: if-statement, select, operators, abap

I convert this condition:

```
LOOP AT gt_zgd_check_smc_st INTO gs_zgd_check_smc_st
    SELECT *
      FROM ever
      INTO wa_ever
      WHERE anlage  EQ wa_euiinstln-anlage
      AND   einzdat <= wa_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio
      AND   auszdat >= wa_zgd_check_smc_st-data_inizio.
    ENDSELECT.
    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
-code error--
ENDIF.
   ENDLOOP.
```

But the client did not like it because it's slower and I changed it into:

```
SELECT * FROM ever 
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_euiinstln 
    WHERE anlage = gt_euiinstln-anlage
    INTO TABLE gt_ever.

...

LOOP AT gt_zgd_check_smc_st INTO gs_zgd_check_smc_st
 ...
 READ TABLE gt_ever INTO gs_ever WITH KEY anlage = gs_euiinstln-anlage.

  IF sy-subrc = 0.

            IF gs_ever-einzdat ?? gs_zgd_check_smc_st-start_date  "date
           AND gs_ever-auszdat ?? gs_zgd_check_smc_st-start_date. "date

         --CODE WITH RECORD ERROR--

   ELSE.
         --- CODE WITH RECORD ERROR ---
      ENDIF.

   ENDLOOP.
```

I don't know which operator is to be inserted after `einzdat` and `auszdat` so that it works like `SELECT-ENDSELECT`.

thank you all
regards.

Comment: You should not code it like you did. You must define `gt_ever` as a sorted table with key components `anlage` and `einzdat`, then access it with both components which will give either an exact match (`sy-subrc = 0`) or before or after (`sy-subrc = 4 or 8`). See [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapread_table.htm) for more information. Note that the lines with same have `anlage` value have in/out dates `einzdat/auszdat` which never overlap, that simplifies the algorithm. I let other people answer if you need exact code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert SELECT-ENDSELECT in for all entries with more table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332812/convert-select-endselect-in-for-all-entries-with-more-table)

Comment: @Raffaele, do not create similar questions, please. Your problem is not with the dates, but in correct structuring of your query: you should analyze the keys from all three tables and combine them into the LOOP by the smallest table utilizing [parallel cursor](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/ABAP+Code+for+Parallel+Cursor+-+Loop+Processing) technique, if possible

Comment: Using a `SELECT. ENDSELECT.` just to check wether a line exists sounds like a bad idea. There is also `SELECT SINGLE` ...

Comment: Maybe I am not really understanding the question, but shouldn't `<=` and `>=` work just as well in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replace

"<=" with LE

">=" with GE

Hope I understand your question right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).